# Checking whether file is opened and write protected in c++

Tags: windows, visual-c++

Using C++ on a Windows XP machine.

1. How can I check if a file is already opened ?
2. How can I distinguish between an already opened file and a write protected file ?

Thanks for help !!

Comment: What's your goal?  To give the user a specific reason why they couldn't open a file?

Answer (score 0):

Easier part first, then the more complicated :-)

2) Use Win32 API `GetFileAttributes` and check for `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY`

1) If the file has been open without an option preventing your access, you can't know

If it's locked, you must try to open it, you'll get a file handle with value `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, and then you can check for example if `GetLastError() == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`

Comment: Thanks 2) works fine, 
1) but i don't know how to open the file. I tried `FILE * fd = fopen(lockFileName.c_str(), "a+");` but I got following compiler warning: `warning C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details`

Comment: Look for the Windows API function CreateFile ... ah why use fopen I thought you were doing Windows API ?